# Switch between Android activities when listview item clicked

Tags: java, android

I searched for hours to find good tutorial about switching between Android activities when a list view item clicked. All tutorials describe about calling different activities for different list view item clicked, but I want to run same activity without considering what item is clicked Here is the code I have used but this is not work.

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt,
                        long paramLong) {
                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderDetails.class);     
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                }
                });
```

Activity called in Manifest.xml

```
</activity>
    <activity android:name=".OrderetDetails"></activity>
</application>
```

How can I do that if it is possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you've misspelt '.OrderDetails' in the manifest.

Comment: @Thomas Owers you are right that was the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick) instead of onItemClick.

Something like this:

```
public void onListItemClick( final ListView l, final View v, final int position, final long id ) {
    Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderDetails.class);     
    startActivity(newActivity);
}
```

Comment: Ok I solved the problem..It is my foolish mistake in Manifest. Thanks for the support!